# MS SQL SELECT INTO table auto generate unique identifier for every row

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier, auto-generate, select-into

I try to create new table in MS SQL server 2008 using `SELECT INTO` statement. I want every row of the new table has auto-generated ID of `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type as a first column.

Code sample without ID column:

```
SELECT m.sellThru, m.turnover
INTO #tmp_table
FROM mpi m
```

Code template with ID (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) column, I want to have as a result:

```
SELECT ?? as id, m.sellThru, m.turnover
INTO #tmp_table
FROM mpi m
```

Desired output is:

```
==============================================================
| id                                   | sellThru | turnover |
==============================================================
| 6818F861-6E87-490D-AF5B-CA9A8B56212E |   155.25 |   110.25 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1A2E8ED6-76A3-42F9-8A87-27050A2ECDC1 |    64.79 |     4.36 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| B0F9F127-56BB-4E87-AC33-626BA13F7065 |   213.89 |    45.89 |
==============================================================
```

Any idea? Except `IDENTITY(INT,1,1)` or `ROW_NUMBER()` which is not want i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy:

```
select newID() as ID, * 
into #temp
from YourTable
```